# how to resolve this emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'WVGA800' solution

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

i am trying to start the android emulator from eclipse classic (`juno`)
 and it keeps giving me this error:

> ERROR: unknown skin name 'WVGA800'

I developed my software using eclipse indigo, but since I installed eclipse juno and imported the same project it started to give me this error. any idea why? and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

My solution was to create a new custom virtual device from the android virtual device manager and use that.

Comment: You created a new custom skin? or what?

Comment: i created a new custom virtual device

Comment: For anyone that's not a constant Android-SDK user, such as myself (I mostly do Cordova), that's wondering how to create your new virtual device: Try `android avd` from the command line, or if you're managing Android SDKs via Eclipse, Window > Android Virtual Device Manager.

Comment: For Android Studio users, it's under Tools > Android > AVD Manager.

Comment: There wasn't any default skin in my default AVD. So I just choose one

Comment: @TMN or you can click that icon with the purple screen and green droid at the bottom right in the toolbar. OR on Mac (not sure of shortcut on Windows) you can click (Command + Shift + A and type AVD) Just a couple of extra options.

Comment: @Waqleh I think since there are solutions that don't involve creating a new device that this particular solution isn't optimal. The error can be resolved by simply toggling the skin in the advanced settings of the ADV in question.

Answer (score 18):

For me on `Mac OS X` this error went away when I selected the skin in advanced setting it was saying is unknown.
[image]

Comment: I did this.... Selected the Pixel_2 skin that I had error, clicked the ... button and then just selected open on the files that where there.

Answer (score 10):

I had the problem and fixed it... Here the main idea of the issue is that the emulator can't find your android-sdk base directory.. so what is the fix? here I will explain..

1. Find where you have installed your sdk. To do so go to Start->All Programs->Android SDK Tools->SDK Manager.. You will see that the path is written on the top of the window.. copy it somewhere so we need it later.. call it "SDK Path"
2. Go to Start and Right Click on Computer and select "Properties".. Then select the last option on the left menu which is "Advanced System Settings".. Go to the "Advanced" tab and click on the "Environment Variables.." on the first list see if there is a variable called "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT".. If it's there then check if the value is the same as the "SDK Path" we copied in the step 1.. if they are not the same then change the value of it to the SDK Path...and check if your problem is solved. if not then go to step 3..
3. If the "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" matches the SDK Path or your problem didn't solve in step 2 then the problem is probably caused by your username.. This was my actual problem. my username had special characters in it like ( !,@,#,... ) or even spaces in some times. Speaking technically as I am myself a programmer, when the emulator program was trying to open the path, it was giving out an error because it couldn't open it because of the special characters..Guessing that the SDK is installed in your Local App Data folder ( Users\\AppData\Local ) as mine was, you should access it with another Enviroment Variable called "LOCALAPPDATA" which links to your Local App Data folder.. So in your SDK Path change the "drive:\Users\\AppData\Local" to "%localappdata" and your problem will be solved .. For example mine was "C:\Users\MiNuS !3\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk" and I changed it to "%localappdata%\Android\android-sdk"... (without the double quotations)..

The same problem is present in some other java programs. I had the problem with the Zend Studio too...

Hope it will solve your problem,
Good Luck

Comment: setting the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in Ubuntu 13.10 did the trick for me too! Thank you!

Comment: I had the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable set, seems Studio||Emulator lost its mind when I killed one of its props

Answer (score 5):

I bumped into the same problem in Android Studio on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and there it helped to create a new AVD with target API Level 17 (the only one available after the standard setup it seems). None of the pre-existing AVDs work, however, only the new one (the old ones all use target APIs lower than 17).

Answer (score 4):

The path to where it looks for the skin is in the ~/.android/avd/$deivce-name$.avd/config.ini

My issue like this occured because I had copied an avd to a different computer and the path was incorrect on that new computer.

Comment: for me, an update to the android-emulator package moved the skins from `/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/resources` to `/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib`. `cd /opt/android-studio; find -name '*your_skin_name*'`... then A manual update of the paths in the avd's `config.ini` helped.

Answer (score 4):

One solution, if you're happy to do this, is to not use a skin. To do this:

1> Tools/AVD Manager

2> Select the device

3> Click the pen icon in the "Actions" Column

4> Uncheck "Enable Device Frame"

Alternatively, if you want to select a preexisting skin, you can click on "Advanced Settings" and scroll down to the "Custom skin definition" drop down box.

And to see instructions on how to create a custom skin, you can click on "Advanced Settings" and scroll down to "How do I create a custom hardware skin", which links to here:  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#skins

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as I moved my `avd` files between systems and as in your case you have moved the relevant files. So the solution as to go to the `.android` folder and make changes to the files with `.ini` of `conf` in their names. In there you will see that the paths to various resources are different as a result of the move you made. So put in the correct path values.

That was how I solved mine.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your AVD manager. `WVGA800` is the default skin for the emulator. You might try to update your software

Comment: every thing is up to date accordion to "Help > Check for Updates".

Comment: at least is there a way to change that skin to something else?

Comment: Yes, you can change the skin by going into your AVD and creating a new device; once you have the device created, there is a drop down for what skin you would like.

Comment: but that drop down list only shows this skin! how can i get other skins?

Comment: i have 2.1, 2.2 and 4.1 installed, and on the "package explorer" it shows android 2.1

Answer (score 1):

As you upgrade your Android Studio, the skin.path value can become no longer valid.  The best approach is to copy the set of screens to your own folder path.  This way the screens are in more permanent folders.

For example for Macbook:

1. Find ~/Applications/Android Studio 1.5.1.0.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
2. Copy device-art-resources folder to a place like ~/dev/device-art-resources
3. For each config.ini in each of your avd folder, change skin.path value to point to the screen of your choice

Answer (score 1):

**For SDK-only installed**

For who has **not installed** Android Studio but has only the SDK, to add a new device, or change a skin to an old device is

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android avd
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to change the skin to **nexus 5x** !!

Answer (score 0):

I solved by uninstalling and reinstall the emulator.

In Android Studio, go to:
Tools -> SDK Manager
Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK
SDK Tools tab
Uncheck the Android Emulator check box, and hit the Apply button.
Do the same, checking the Android Emulator check box.