# Samsung Galaxy S II AVD (Android Virtual Device) - "emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'galaxy_s2'"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to create my first ever (Android) app using Eclipse.

I've almost set up the AVD for the Samsung Galaxy SII (thanks to another question - [Samsung Galaxy S II AVD (Android Virtual Device) Basic Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings)), but I am still encountering a problem, which prevents me from getting it to work.

Whenever I try and launch the simulator (using the AVD Manager), the following message comes up:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Samsung_Galaxy_SII_1'
>
> emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'galaxy_s2'

I have a feeling it might be to do with where various files are stored/the directory where my Eclipse is set up. Any advice on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you point to your android-sdk directory? Another idea is to create a custom emulator build. Saw it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11894396/645270).

Answer (score 0):

Have you [downloaded](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-S2-Skin-for-handset-emulation) the skin into the skins folder? (..sdk directory.../platforms/android-10/skins)

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Developers provides its emulator skins, check out the below url.

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do?pi=1&ps=10&pb=Y&ct=CT350000&sc=

Comment: Could you post some content from the link?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of 

the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers will not be of any 

use if the external linked page changes in future

Comment: @Robert I agree with Panther, you may find the skins through the [link](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do?pi=1&ps=10&pb=Y&ct=CT350000&sc=) above or you can check Samsung Developers website.