# phonegap run android can't run with: ERROR: unknown skin name 'WXGA720'

Tags: cordova

I'm on OSX and when I run

```
$ phonegap run android
```

It errors out with a:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
WARNING : No started emulators found, starting an emulator.
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'WXGA720'
```

I've set both `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` to `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`.

full log: https://gist.github.com/Celc/c8ecadd2f533a6b06f89

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10616), have you set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`to a defined value ?

To put in the form of a statement, set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.

Have you tried `android avd` as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894396/how-to-resolve-this-emulator-error-unknown-skin-name-wvga800-solution) ?

Comment: I've tried doing that, but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Ah the issue was that the android avd had old out of date items. Once I created a new one it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kit, can you tell me how you did it?